# Ambiguous type variable `f0' in the constraint: Haskell

Tags: haskell

Note: there may be some typos (capitals etc) as my wireless card has broken on my computer and I cant install haskell on this one, so I am re-typing the code (and I dont have a memory stick xD)

I have been using
        `Config line values 2 2`
to define a Config but I just doesn't like this one function 'start'. Anything that takes an f -> f works fine though...

```
data Config = Config {
                     line :: Line,
                    nums :: [Nums],
                    indent :: Indent,
                       run :: Run
}  deriving (Eq, Show)

class (Result f) => Test f where 
          start :: Line -> [Nums] -> f

 instance Test Config where 
      start line nums = Config line nums 0 0
```

If I run

```
 > start 2 [0,0,0]
```

which should return

```
 > Config 2 [0,0,0] 0 0
```

I get the error:

```
 Ambiguous type variable `f0' in the constraint:
  (Test f0) arising from a use of `start'
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

running

```
> :t Config 2 [0,0,0] 0 0
```

gives

```
> Config 2 [0,0,0] 0 0 :: Config
```

which is correct

Comment: What `Test` class are you using?

Comment: Can you tell us in what situation you get the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, just what the message says,

```
start 2 [0,0,0]
```

can have *any* type that is an instance of `Test`. The compiler has no way of finding out without you telling it, either directly with a type signature,

```
> start 2 [0,0,0] :: Config
```

should work without problem, or by supplying context from which the type can be inferred,

```
> indent $ start 2 [0,0,0]
```

should also work because the type can now be inferred by the type of `indent` that uses the result of `start`.

You probably expected the compiler to choose the type `Config` because at the moment, that's the only instance of `Test`. But the compiler never selects an instance because there is no other instance it knows of, since that could break code when other instances are added in different modules.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that as constructed, the expression `start 2 [0,0,0,0]` could return *any* type that belongs to class `Test`. The system has no way to that in that instance you want it to return a `Config`. If you cast it explicitly, ie

```
start 2 [0,0,0] :: Config
```

that ought to work.